# Hunter devon park 5 ceiling fan

Tags: wiring

I brought a cealing fan but it has a white wire , black wire , and a blue wire coming out of the fan . But in my cealing I only have a black wire and a white wire . And wanted to ask how do I safely wire the fan . ? It has a built in remote control receiver.  . The old fan was a hunter as well and the fan had 3 wires . But 2 of them went on the black wire and the white wire went on the white wire . And that cealing fan had a light kit as well and the one I am speaking about . Can someone help me with this ??

Answer (score 1):

If you have a single switch to control the fan, both the blue and black wires should be connected to the black power wire.

Answer (score 0):

If the fan has a wireless remote with separate controls for the fan and the light, then it will have a receiver module which is placed inside the fan shroud. The receiver module is a switch which has as its input a switched hot from a single wall switch and it will output a switched hot to the fan wire (usually the black) and will output a separate switched hot to the light (usually blue). You leave the wall  switch on and control the fans and lights with the remote. If the wall switch is off, then everything is off and the remote has no effect.

The receiver may also accept the white neutral but this is common to both the fan and light so there is only one neutral. Or the receiver may not accept the neutral and so that is connected directly to the single white lead in the fan. The receiver may also have a connection for the ground from the wall switch box.

In my experience, the Hunter fans with battery powered remote control are designed to be a drop-in replacement for a ceiling fixture which has a single switch but allows the fan and the light to be controlled independently with the remote. If you didn't have this remote and receiver, you would have to use the pull chains to control the fan and lights separately.

The Hunter fans with remote I have installed have a caddy for the remote that fits over the wall switch, but allows the wall switch to be turned off if the remote is removed from the caddy. This is useful because I have had an instance when the receiver became unresponsive to the remote. In that case to restore function what is needed is to momentarily depower the receiver. This is easily done by turning off the wall switch then tuning it back on (maybe with a 30 sec delay).

These fans will work without a wall switch installed, but in that case you would have to use the circuit breaker to depower the receiver and this would affect everything on the circuit.